# Mailchimp Surveys - Webhooks or API?

Tags: api, webhooks, mailchimp

Mailchimp seems to have "Surveys" -- which are nicely integrated (so it is claimed!) with their own database, so that the subscriber gets updated/added in the audience as appropriate when a survey is filled, etc.

I have a client who is interested in using these but also would like to integrate the survey response data into Salesforce.

I tried looking into Mailchimp API reference and cannot find anything related to surveys. Ideally, it would be best if they were supported by the Webhooks, since that is the functionality the client is interested in, however, I am open to using polling-based method if that's the only way available.

Thank you in advance!!